# Text mining of machine logs to find correlation between errors in R

Tags: r, correlation, text-mining, hierarchical-clustering, apriori

I've with me 50 MB data from a machine consisting of event logs such as device status, warning and error. I wish to perform text mining on the same to find correlation between errors i.e. one error could trigger another in future and take a prescriptive action on it. I've used hierarchical clustering in R to generate a dendrogram but the result couldn't yeild expected insight. Hence, I've planned to perform Apriori Algorithm on the same. My queries are:

Is Hierarchical Clustering suggested to find such correlations?
Is Apriori an apt algorithm in such situation and why? Or, is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please do not cross-post.

Comment: @gung - I posted the same question in StackOverflow but was directed by someone to post the same in CrossValidated for better answers.

Comment: Fair enough, but you need to wait to let them migrate your post here.

Comment: @gung - Okay, Thanks, I'm actually new to StackOverflow and didn't know about this migration that other users could do it